# Depth Buffer doesn't work Opengl es on android

Tags: android, opengl-es, depth-buffer

i wrote a Vertex Shader with a projection algorithm already in it, so i didn't use a projection Matrix. For some Reason when i enable depth Buffer, the screen stays completely blanc. In the Vertex Shader i pass the distance from the camera to the vertex for z and w. I wrot these lines, in the onSurfaceCreated to activate the depth buffer:

```
GLES30.glEnable(GLES30.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
GLES30.glDepthFunc(GLES30.GL_LEQUAL);
GLES30.glDepthMask( true );
```

to activate the depth buffer

This is the Vertex Shader:

```
#version 300 es
in vec3 aPos;
out vec4 lColor;
uniform vec4 vm;

void main()
{
vec4 rColor = vec4(sin(aPos.x * aPos.x), sin(aPos.y * aPos.y), sin(aPos.z * aPos.z),1.0f);
lColor = rColor;

float x2 = (aPos.x * cos(vm.y) - (aPos.z) * sin(vm.y));
float z2 = ((aPos.x * sin(vm.y) + (aPos.z) * cos(vm.y))) + 7.0f;

float y2 = (aPos.y * cos(vm.z) - (z2 - 7.0f) * sin(vm.z));
float z3 = ((aPos.y * sin(vm.z) + (z2 - 7.0f) * cos(vm.z))) + 7.0f;

float dst = sqrt((aPos.x * aPos.x) + (aPos.y * aPos.y) + (aPos.z *  aPos.z));
gl_Position = vec4(x2 / z3 * vm.x,y2 / z3 * vm.x  * vm.w, dst ,dst);
```

}

The first two lines in main, are just for generating a more or less random color, and the following four are for rotation, so you can just ignore those.

Comment: How do you create the OpenGL context and window? Does the default framebuffer even have a depth buffer?

Comment: i'm new to opengl es, but i think, there is only one way to create a openGL view, with the GLSurfaceView and I have no idea, what a frame buffer is

Comment: but, i did copy some code from the internet, and i think it has someting to do with it:EGL10.EGL_LEVEL, 0,
                EGL10.EGL_RENDERABLE_TYPE, 4,  // EGL_OPENGL_ES2_BIT
                EGL10.EGL_COLOR_BUFFER_TYPE, EGL10.EGL_RGB_BUFFER,
                EGL10.EGL_RED_SIZE, 8,
                EGL10.EGL_GREEN_SIZE, 8,
                EGL10.EGL_BLUE_SIZE, 8,
                EGL10.EGL_DEPTH_SIZE, 16,
                EGL10.EGL_SAMPLE_BUFFERS, 1,
                EGL10.EGL_SAMPLES, 4,  // This is for 4x MSAA.
                EGL10.EGL_NONE

Comment: Post your vertex shader please.